# What is the correct usage of ComponentModelCreated to manage Windsor lifestyles?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, castle-windsor

I am trying to use tje ComponentModelCreated event of the Castle Windsor Kernal to manage the Lifestyle of my components.

The problem is that the event doesn't seem to fire at all? I must be using it incorrectly some how? Please see my code below, I would love to know where I am going wrong.

Thanks.

In my Application_Start:

```
Container = new WindsorContainer().Install(FromAssembly.This());
Container.Kernel.ComponentModelCreated += WindsorExtension.Kernel_ComponentModelCreated;
```

The method:

```
public static void Kernel_ComponentModelCreated(ComponentModel model)
        {
            if (model.LifestyleType == LifestyleType.Undefined && model.Name.EndsWith("Controller"))
            {
                model.LifestyleType = LifestyleType.Transient;
            }
            else if (model.LifestyleType == LifestyleType.Undefined)
            {
                model.LifestyleType = LifestyleType.PerWebRequest;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure about the part where you say

> the event doesn't seem to fire at all

It works on my machine...

As for the underlying problem, event handlers like that are **not** the right place to modify the `ComponentModel` itself.

Use a [ComponentModel construction contributor](http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.ComponentModel-construction-contributors.ashx) for that.